# Finding zeroes of a numerical solution of an ODE in Maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I have a system of ODEs involving many variables, say 20, 
and I have solved this system numerically by Maple for a particular initial condition.

When I plotted these solutions it was clear that each variable $a_n(t)$ viewed as a function of time, has a unique root. 
Is there a Maple command which gives me an approximate value of these roots?

What I am doing now is simply probing onto the graph and try to find the root by locating the cursor, but I feel very stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple methodology might be to use the `output=listprocedure` option of [dsolve,numeric](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve/numeric). That means that you can easily obtain callable procedures for each of the dependent variables. You could then use those individually with `fsolve` or `RootFinding:-Nextzero` to compute the roots..

But perhaps a more robust (and possibly efficient) way would be to use the [events](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve/numeric/Events) facilities within `dsolve,numeric` itself.

ps. This site is for math, not programming. stackoverflow or mapleprimes are more suitable forums for this topic.